# MDB is not listening the messages from the queue in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, mq

We are using  WAS 8.5 and at the specific point of time the  MDB which is configured to queue stops listening.We have checked the server logs and application logs there is no clues or errors related to this issue. Is there any specific reasons or situations where we face this kind of situations.

Comment: Has the listener port stopped?

Comment: No. listener port is active only. but from the logs we can see that the MDB is not picking the message from the queue.

Comment: What type of MQ - IBM MQ?  Have you checked that messages are on the queue?

Comment: If the listener port is active and mapped to the queue and the MDB is bound to the listener port (check the bindings) and the system is running, I can't see any reason why it would not read any messages on the queue.

Comment: Because of MDB is not listening, Messages were piled up in the queue and we got the queue full error message.